# Sum of columns from Tablix in textBox shows #ERROR in RDLC

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc

I have a `tablix` in `RDLC` and a `TextBox` below the `tablix`. Now I want the sum of a particular column in `TextBox`. I used an expression for the sum.

The expression is as per below....

```
=Sum(Fields!Col.Value, "DataSource")
```

I am taking the sum of the records from data set. But shows me error. The typeof `TextBox` is `number`.

Below is the image of the output of the `Report Viewer`.

[image]

What is wrong? Or how to do it?

Comment: where is the C# herE ?

Comment: I am making WinForm application in C#.net.

Comment: I mean show your code and please the part which is the problem. Do you narrow your problem with debugging ?

Comment: I tried to debug my program. Shows records perfectly in `Tablix`. And How to debug `TextBox` in `RDLC`?

Comment: The type of TextBox is more related to formatting, not actual data type. What is the data type of the field in dataset? Are there any NULL values? Did you try to change expression to =Sum(CDbl(Fields!Col.Value))?

Comment: @InitK : It helped, actually it solved the query. I had to `=Sum(CDec...`, as the fields are type of `Decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

For sum you have to convert filed to double then you can use sum. **CDbl(Filed!somethingCol.Value)** use this function for conversion.

Change your code to below

```
=Sum(CDbl(Fields!Col.Value), "DataSource")
```